# Easily add term to vocabulary with long list of terms

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

A client is complaining about the way on how to **add terms** to a vocabulary in taxonomy.

It's a **long list of terms and sub-terms**. So I told him when he adds a term he can select a **Parent term** and set the **weight** in the **Relations** block.

But the list of parent terms is long and not very clear. Isn't there a way to make this more user friendly? Maybe search in parent terms or .. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the default terms are added to a vocabulary is not so nice indeed, and we get to hear this kind of complaints often.
But, there is a module which is made exactly for this purpose :)
Check [Taxonomy CSV import/export](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv).

> This module allows you to import or export taxonomy from or to a CSV (comma-separated values) file or with a copy-and-paste text.
>
> It helps you to quick import a non-standardized vocabulary, for example an old thesaurus, a hierarchical taxonomy or a simple list of children, synonyms, descriptions, weights or related terms to terms. It can be used as a module or as an API with a plug-in mechanism. It can manage internationalized vocabularies with i18n_taxonomy, a submodule of i18n module [Drupal 7 only].

After that you just have to train the client on how to import the terms. The terms can be added in a single configuration textarea and can be comma separated.

Answer (score 2):

For better UI management of taxonomy terms try [Taxonomy Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager)

```
This module provides a powerful interface for managing taxonomies. A vocabulary gets displayed in a dynamic tree view, where parent terms can be expanded to list their nested child terms or can be collapsed.

The Taxonomy Manager has following operations and key features:

 - dynamic treeview
 - mass deleting
 - mass adding of new terms
 - moving of terms in hierarchies
 - merging of terms (using the Term merge module in 7.x)
 - fast weight changing with up and down arrows (and AJAX saving)
 - AJAX powered term editing form
 - simple search interface
 - CSV Export of terms
 - i18n support for multilingual vocabularies (per language terms)
 - Double Tree interface for moving terms in hierarchies, adding new
   translations and switching terms between different vocabularies
```